# Issue Creating Org Assets Library (CDN)

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, administration, pnp-powershell, asset-library

I'm attempting to create an organizational assets library for use with company branded templates and copilot features.

I have successfully run this code on my development tenant, but when attempting to run the same code in our production tenant, I receive this error:

> This library is not on the site that contains other organization asset libraries.

I've tried this on multiple site collections and even created a new communication site, but the error persists.

```
# Install and import the PnP PowerShell module
Install-Module -Name PnP.PowerShell -Force -AllowClobber
Import-Module -Name PnP.PowerShell -Force


# Connect to SharePoint with MFA
$authUrl = "https://<siteurl>.sharepoint.com/sites/OrgAssets";
 $pnp = Connect-PnPOnline -Url $authUrl -Interactive
$libraryUrl = "https://<siteUrl>.sharepoint.com/sites/OrgAssets/Assets"

 Get-PnPOrgAssetsLibrary
#$test = Get-PnPOrgNewsSite -Connection $pnp

#Remove-PnPOrgAssetsLibrary -LibraryUrl $libraryUrl
Add-PnPOrgAssetsLibrary -LibraryUrl $libraryUrl #-CdnType Private -OrgAssetType OfficeTemplateLibrary

# Disconnect from SharePoint
Disconnect-PnPOnline
```

Comment: What happens when you run this command: `Get-PnPOrgAssetsLibrary`? Do you see any existing org asset library from "another" site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the Microsoft official documentation, [Create an organization assets library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/organization-assets-library),

> All organization asset libraries must be on the same site.

So, try this:

1. Firstly, check if you have any existing organization asset libraries in your Microsoft 365 tenant using this command:

```
Get-PnPOrgAssetsLibrary
```

2. Create a new document library on **same** SharePoint site where your existing organization asset libraries are created.
3. Run the following command to designate the new document library as an organization assets library:

```
Add-PnPOrgAssetsLibrary -LibraryUrl $libraryUrl
```

**References**:

1. [Get-PnPOrgAssetsLibrary](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Get-PnPOrgAssetsLibrary.html?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224)
2. [Add-PnPOrgAssetsLibrary](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Add-PnPOrgAssetsLibrary.html?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224)
3. [Create an Organization Assets Library in SharePoint Online](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2024/01/30/create-an-organization-assets-library-in-sharepoint-online?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224)
4. [Register SharePoint Document Library as an Organization Assets Library using PowerShell](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2024/02/03/register-sharepoint-document-library-as-an-organization-assets-library-using-powershell?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224)

Comment: Just one additional I had to add to you code to get the relative URL
$orgInfo = Get-PnPOrgAssetsLibrary
$orgInfo[0].LibraryUrl